# The right way to do sprite-based animation in Svelte

Tags: image, animation, dom, svelte

I have a few dozens of png files (of the same size), and would like to use them for simple animation. (The images are taken from the classic "xneko" program.)

Right now, my neko.svelte looks like:

```
<script>
  export let position = {left: 100, top: 100};
  let current = 0;

  let names = [
    'awake', 'down1', 'down2', 'dtogi1', 'dtogi2', 'dwleft1', 'dwleft2',
    'dwright1', 'dwright2', 'jare2', 'kaki1', 'kaki2', 'left1', 'left2',
    'ltogi1', 'ltogi2', 'mati2', 'mati3', 'right1', 'right2', 'rtogi1', 'rtogi2',
    'sleep1', 'sleep2', 'up1', 'up2', 'upleft1', 'upleft2',
    'upright1', 'upright2', 'utogi1', 'utogi2'
  ];

  setInterval(() => current = (current + 1) % names.length, 100);
</script>

<style>
  .neko {
    position: relative;
  }
</style>

<div class='neko' style="
  left: {position.left + 'px'};
  top: {position.top + 'px'};
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;">
{#each names as name (name)}
  <img id={name} width=32 height=32
       style='display: {names[current] === name ? "inherit" : "none"}'
       src={'https://tinlizzie.org/~ohshima/neko/neko/' + name + '.png'} alt={name}/>
{/each}
</div>
```

(The actual logic for picking an image is a bit more involved, but it is simplified here for illustration purposes. And `position` is passed in from the owning component. you can see it running here: https://tinlizzie.org/~ohshima/neko/)

This works okay. But I wonder if there is a better way than having to all img elements in the display scene yet just show one of them by not having `display: none`.  If it is done in straight DOM, it'd create the list of img elements and append one of those to a div. But it does not seem that I can write something like:

```
<script>
let allImages = ...;                     // a dictionary of img elements
let currentImg = allIamges[name];        // an img element
</script>

<div class='neko'>{currentImg}</div> // reference to the img
```

Please let me know what is the suggested way to do a sprite animation like this.

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to do sprite-based animation, with or without Svelte, is to generate a *spritesheet* of all the images together, and then animate with with CSS. So you'd have an image like this...

[image: Neko spritesheet]

...and a 32px by 32px div, and change the `background-position` every 100ms. This has a few benefits:

- No flashes while images load the first time — either they're all there, or none of them are
- Fewer HTTP requests
- Typically a spritesheet will be a decent amount smaller than the sum of the individual files
- Less work for the browser to do, as there's a single element, and you're not changing the structure of the document at all

As coincidence would have it I wrote a spritesheet generator called [sevenup](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/sevenup) for a project last week. Running those images through it gave me the spritesheet above, together with a bunch of CSS.

My Neko.svelte component looks like this:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    const names = [
    'awake', 'down1', 'down2', 'dtogi1', 'dtogi2', 'dwleft1', 'dwleft2',
    'dwright1', 'dwright2', 'jare2', 'kaki1', 'kaki2', 'left1', 'left2',
    'ltogi1', 'ltogi2', 'mati2', 'mati3', 'right1', 'right2', 'rtogi1', 'rtogi2',
    'sleep1', 'sleep2', 'up1', 'up2', 'upleft1', 'upleft2',
    'upright1', 'upright2', 'utogi1', 'utogi2'
  ];

    let current = 0;
    $: name = names[current];

    onMount(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            current = (current + 1) % names.length;
        }, 100);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    });
</script>

<div data-sevenup="{name}.png" style="transform: translate({pos.x}px,{pos.y}px)"></div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```css
[data-sevenup] { background-image: url(./sprites.png); background-size: 192px 192px }
[data-sevenup="awake.png"] { width: 32px; height: 32px; background-position: 0px 0px }
[data-sevenup="down1.png"] { width: 32px; height: 32px; background-position: -32px 0px }
[data-sevenup="down2.png"] { width: 32px; height: 32px; background-position: 0px -32px }
[data-sevenup="dtogi1.png"] { width: 32px; height: 32px; background-position: -32px -32px }
...
```

Putting it all together, the app looks like this: https://svelte.dev/repl/b66dbc755bf84053914350c2f07d5f2a?version=3.12.1

Comment: Thank you so much. The flickering was one issue I had, and it is nice not to have to keep multiple img elements.

Comment: That's really nice ! I'm curious though shouldn't `requestAnimationFrame` be used for that ?

Comment: No. `requestAnimationFrame` runs sixty times a second (assuming no delays). In this case, the frame should only change ten times a second.